# Calculating $\lim_{x\to\infty}(a^x+b^x-c^x) \ ; \lim_{x\to0}(a^x+b^x-c^x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponentiation

Calculate: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(a^x+b^x-c^x) \ ; \lim_{x\to0}(a^x+b^x-c^x)  \ :\forall a>b>c>0$.

First of all, is it actually necessary to check all 5 possibilities for $c=1, c>1,b=1,a=1,a>1$ ?

I also run into trouble for $a=1$, I chose some arbitrary numbers to make it easier to see:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+(\frac 1 2)^x-(\frac 1 3)^x)= 1+0-0=1$ but if I make a small change by dividing by $(\frac 1 3)^x$: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(3^x+(\frac 3 2)^x-1)=\infty\neq 1$, so why it's apparently wrong to divide by smallest element here ?

Comment: Three cases (the size of $a$) will be enough. Your calculation for $a=1$ has a mistake: $b^x$ and $c^x$ die. More cases are needed if we replace $a\gt b\gt c\gt 0$ by $a\ge b\ge c\ge 0$.

Comment: Right in the first part, but in the divided version they don't die, why is that ?

Comment: By the way, I was only looking at the limit as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: What you call the divided version I would call the multiplied version. If you multiply something that has limit $1$ by $3^x$, naturally it will blow up.

Comment: But aren't they basically the same function: $3^x+(\frac 3 2)^x-1=1+(\frac 1 2)^x-(\frac 1 3)^x$ ? Like $4x+2=2x+1$

Comment: They are not. The one on the left is enormously bigger, for large $x$. And $4x+2$ is not the same as $2x+1$.  You may be getting confused because of the fact that when we are trying ro find the limit of $A/B$, it is sometimes handy to divide $A$ and $B$ by the same thing, leaving the *ratio* unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=b/a<1$ and $C=c/a<1$
$$
a^x+b^x-c^x=a^x(1+B^x-C^x)
$$
What is $\lim_{x\to\infty}r^x$ when $0<r<1$?

Now divide in the cases $0<a<1$, $a=1$ and $a>1$.

For the limit at $0$ is there any problem in showing it is $1$?